# Start and stop selenium server using ruby

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to start selenium server from the ruby file 
which I am running? I mean, when I try to run my script, it should 
automatically start selenium server and at the end of test it should 
stop the server. Is there any way to do this from ruby file?

Comment: You can use `system`, `exec` or backticks to execute system commands.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Read in "Rake" section in selenium-client gem rdoc.
Or just start/stop it from exec method =)